# Which is faster for searching strings regex or find() of Python?

Tags: python, xml, string-matching

I have an XML string

```
<tags>
   <person1>dave jones</person1>
   <person2>ron matthews</person2>
   <person3>sally van heerden</person3>
   <place>tygervalley</place>
   <ocassion>shopping</ocassion>
</tags>
```

and I would like to search this xml string using search terms such as "Sally Van Heerden" or "Tygervalley"

Is it faster to use regex to find the terms in this string or is the find() method of Python fast enough? I can also search using the element tree XML parser for python and then build the XML tree then searching it but I fear it will be too slow.

Which of the above three is the fastest?
Also any other suggestions?

Keep in mind that there can be multiple search terms entered and also multiple(Thousands) XML strings will be searched.

Update : what about splitting the xml string into a list, removing all special characters and then turning the list into a set and also a set of the search terms. Then get the intersection of the two sets? Would this be fast?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to parse the XML into an efficiently-searchable data structure instead of worrying about how to search the XML directly?

Comment: Do you have some extreme performance requirements? If not, don't try to optimize what doesn't need to be optimized.

Comment: Use the [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) module to find out.

Comment: @ThiefMaster The performance requirements aren't extreme, its just that I have to extract the xml data from thousands of image files and then match the terms entered by a user with the xml data of each image

Comment: @user1401950: Then you should be a bit clearer if you want to do **text** search or **semantic** search.  Because if you want to do XML-aware processing you should be using an XML parser (in whatever flavour you like: DOM, SAX or pull)

Comment: @C2H5OH its text search, the user searches for images by entering search terms. e.g. user enters "dog" the returned result is all images which contain the XML tag or text with the word "dog"

Comment: For that matter, an XSLT with a parameter for the search term could be a very clean approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly I think you'd have to have some very extreme speed requirements for this to be your bottleneck, but even if you do, *the only way you can make an informed decision about this is by testing*.

Here's a start, searching that string using `find`/`re.findall` for one string.  I doubt that this is representative of your use case though, you will need to determine what queries you'll be running and test those.

```
% python -mtimeit "'<tags> <person1>dave jones</person1> <person2>ron matthews</person2> <person3>sally van heerden</person3> <place>tygervalley</place> <ocassion>shopping</ocassion> </tags>'.find('tygervalley')"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.279 usec per loop

% python -mtimeit "import re; re.findall('tygervalley', '<tags> <person1>dave jones</person1> <person2>ron matthews</person2> <person3>sally van heerden</person3> <place>tygervalley</place> <ocassion>shopping</ocassion> </tags>')"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.65 usec per loop
```

Like I said though, it's hard to imagine that this difference is the most important bottle neck in your program.

Comment: It may be worth noting that `find` only looks for the first match whereas `re.findall()` will keep looking and return a list of all matches. So you can't really compare the two.

Answer (score 1):

Regular Expressions go through a long process of compiling, and then searching through a string following a complex set of rules.  The `find` function goes through the string in one pass.

The `find` function will give better performance if patterns aren't needed.

Comment: But if the searches are ongoing, the compiled regex could be stored in memory.

Comment: If we used just one needle it would look like, `(a|b|c|d|e|f|g)` where each letter represents one possible match.  Before the search started, all inputs would have to be escaped for special characters and then joined together to form the needle.  At every character in the XML the RegEx engine would check if any of the words could potentially match before proceeding to the next character.  In short, I can almost guarantee it would take longer.

Comment: @kojiro etree.ElementTree is for parsing xml which then builds a tree, would you say its a efficiently-searchable data structure?

Comment: @user1401950 please move this question up to the main comment thread since it's not really related to this answer.